# Change order status for custom module

Tags: magento2, php, module, payment-methods, magento2.4

I want to use one offline payment method module, I install this [module](https://github.com/Vendic/magento2-offline-payments)

is there any way to change the status of the order to be Processing instead of Pending? Right now all my orders have status Pending and I really need to be Processing.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml` with the following code.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="sales_order_place_after">
            <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\OrderObserver" />
       </event>
   </config>
   ```
2. you need to create Observer file at following location.

   ```
   app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderObserver.php


   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;

   use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

   class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
   {
      public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
      {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        //NOW APPLY YOUR LOGIC HERE TO CHECK ORDER PAYMENT METHOD AND BASED ON THAT CHANGE THERE STATUS
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Hi, your code is not work is redirect back to the Shopping Cart page ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Add bellow code in your custom module etc\events.xml

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
   <observer name="custom_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomOrderObserver" />
</event>
```

2. Create CustomOrderObserver file

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $order->setStatus('processing);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, is not work, after I place the code where you say My checkout page is redirect back to Shopping Cart page, you have any idea why?